# Чи треба ставити кому перед "абощо"?

Tags: пунктуація

Я завжди гадав, що як і перед *"тощо"*, перед *"абощо"* кома не ставиться, як можна бачити й з прикладів [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/aboshho).

Але [тут](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53392/29910.html) у прикладах перед *"абощо"* всюди коми.

**За яких умов перед *"абощо"* треба ставити кому?**

Answer (score 7):

Сайт "Російсько-українські словники" [каже](http://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/spoluchnyky) наступне про *тощо*:

> *тощо* — як прикінцева частка після однорядних членів речення на
> означення незакінчености однорядних членів звичайно не відділяється
> комою від попереднього слова за її вимовою (але див. *абощо*)

Але *абощо* потрібно виділяти комою:

> Так само здебільшого й перед абощо: Ходи вже, абощо! (Сл. Гр.)

<del>Як бачимо, ресурс посилається на словник Грінченка, хоча в цьому словнику і [близько такого немає](https://www.google.com.ua/search?num=20&client=firefox-b-ab&q=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE%20site%3Ahrinchenko.com&oq=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE%20site%3Ahrinchenko.com&gs_l=serp.3...27742.27742.0.28094.1.1.0.0.0.0.106.106.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.0.0.ckCuL1kuKfE).</del>

<del>Думаю, можна просто керуватися правописом. І тощо, і абощо - складні сполучники. В §118. КОМА, розділі "А. Кома в простому реченні" [немає нічого](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par118) про такі сполучники, які вживаємо після переліку чогось, тому можна писати без коми.</del>

**UPD.** Поспішив я з висновками та написанням відповіді. Тому трохи виправлень та доповнень.

*По-перше*, дякую [Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/4/sasha) за підказку, що в словнику Грінченка [насправді є](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/18-abo.html#show_point) інформація про даний сполучник, проте там його подано через дефіс: *або-що*.

*По-друге*, за українським правописом 2015 року слова *тощо* і *абощо* є складними сполучниками:

- [В параграфі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par33) про написання складних сполучників:

  > § 32. Сполучники
  >
  > 1. Разом пишуться складні сполучники, які становлять тісне поєднання повнозначних слів із частками або прийменниками: адже,
  >    аніж, втім,
  >    зате, мовби, начеб, начебто, немов, немовби, немовбито, неначе,
  >    неначебто, ніби, нібито, ніж, отже, отож, притім, притому, причім,
  >    причому, проте, себто, тобто, цебто, щоб, якби, якщо; також слова:
  >    **абощо**, **тощо**.
- [В параграфі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par33) про написання часток:

  > § 33. Частки
  >
  > А. Словотвірні частки пишуться разом, окремо або через дефіс.
  >
  > 1. Разом пишуться:
  >
  >    б) частки би (б), то, що в складі сполучників: щоб, якби, немовбито,
  >    нібито, **абощо** (...)

**АЄДА**(але є два але). "Словник.ua" [каже](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%C0%C1%CE%D9%CE) без посилань на будь-які джерела, що *абощо* - це частка, а Вікісловник = що це взагалі [прислівник](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE) (???).

*По-третє*, можна спробувати розібратися, як колись писали і як зараз варто писати *абощо*.

Почати варто з встановлення чіткої семантичної різниці між *тощо* та *абощо*. В цьому допоможе ABBYY Lingvo, який про перше слово [каже](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Interpret/uk-en/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE):

> Уживається в кінці переліку чого-небудь як вказівка на його неповноту,
> на можливість його продовження; і таке інше.

А про *абощо* [наступне](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Interpret/uk-en/%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE):

> Уживається в разі переліку предметів (явищ і т. ін.) замість
> останнього з них, що не визначається; чи що, чи що інше, чи щось
> подібне.

З цього можна зробити висновок (правильний він чи ні - скаже спільнота), що *тощо* стосується всього переліку, а не є його частиною, тому на нього правила пунктуації не поширюються. Інша справа з *абощо* - воно стоїть **замість** останнього предмету, тобто ми наче останній член переліку замінили на *або щось інше*.

Тепер подивімося на приклади використання та написання. Гарним матеріалом для цього може бути роман "Люборацькі" Анатолія Свидницького (написаний 1861-62 рр., виданий 1886 року, тобто якраз в період формування словника Грінченка). Хоча автор й деколи ставить кому перед *абощо*, деколи ні, все ж можна побачити закономірність в більшості використань. До прикладу:

- > З ласки та на втіху: от або замужичиш, **абощо**.

  "Або замужичиш, або щось інше".
- > Хоч і видерусь **абощо**, то нігде сховатись

  "Видерусь або щось інше".
- > (...) щоб котрий або плечем здвигнув, **абощо** (...)

  "Або плечем здвигнув, або щось інше"

Тобто, на мою думку, можна застосувувати правила для однорідних членів речення: якщо присутнє лише *абощо*, коми не ставимо, якщо перед останнім предментом переліку є *або*, дивимося на наступне правило:

> § 118. КОМА (,)
>
> А. Кома в простому реченні
>
> У простому реченні кома ставиться:
>
> 2. Між однорідними членами речення, з’єднаними двома або більше однаковими сполучниками: і...і (й...й), ні...ні (ані...ані), то...то
>    (не то...не то), чи...чи (чи то...чи то), **або...або**.

Але Свидницький, як і багато інших сучасних і не дуже письменників, часто ставлять кому дуже по-різному. Наприклад:

> Та так з п'ять, **абощо**.
>
> І знайшов таку хорошу — щоб де струпочок **абощо**
>
> (...) а там не всі йому піддавались — не того, що він не вміє, **абощо** (...)
>
> А там ще й на празник **абощо** загримить з Антосьом в гості на село.

Comment: Цікаво, що СУМ-11 наводить ті ж самі цитати з М. Вовчок в статті «[Абощо](http://sum.in.ua/s/aboshho)», але вже без ком.

Comment: Хм, r2u правий — всі цитати зі статті «Абощо» із СУМ-11, окрім Степана Васильченка, насправді в старих виданнях писалися з комами (це показує пошук по гугл-книжках).

Comment: Я так розумію, r2u просто оцифрував і виклав "Норми української літературної мови О. Синявський 1941" (звідти ці цитати). Те, що було нормою в 1941 році зараз зовсім не обов'язково є нормою.
Аргумент про те, що якщо в правописі не згадано, то можна кому й не ставити цікавий, проте там є лише "V. НАЙГОЛОВНІШІ ПРАВИЛА ПУНКТУАЦІЇ", тому не дуже переконливий...
Дякую за відповідь, але, сподіваюся, знайдеться щось більш чітке й офіційне )

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55169/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Answer (score 1):

З «Пунктуаційного словника-довідника» Зеновія Терлака:

> **АБОЩО**. Сполучник, що вживається при переліку замість останнього компонента, який не визначається. Кома перед **абощо** не ставиться. Наприклад: Їй прийшло до голови, що вона може не знайти Остапа, бо нічим не значила своєї дороги. Треба було ламати комиш **абощо**. (М. Коцюбинський).